# Using HttpClient to Send Dates in URL Using AttributeRouting

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I'm having some problems getting a date range query accepted by my WebAPI.  As as far as I can tell from everything I've read this should be working but I still get `400 Bad Request` responses.

My API route looks like this:

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [GET("range/{start:datetime}/{end:datetime}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(DateTime start, DateTime end)
```

I'm using the `AttributeRouting` library and according to [this page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/create-a-rest-api-with-attribute-routing) the URL I'm requesting should be fine.

My request URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:51258/plots/range/2013-07-29T21:58:39/2013-08-05T21:58:39
```

I have this set on the controller `RoutePrefix("plots")` which is where the `plots` bit of the URL route comes from.

If I strip the times off the `DateTime` objects everything works fine but I need the times passed.

Comment: It might be because that isn't a standard DateTime format in C#. The date part is fine, and so is the time, however the T in between them makes it non standard. I would try replacing it with a space. If that works then you'll know what needs to be done.

Comment: I've added the T since it didn't work with a space or an encoded space either.  According to Mike Wasson (in the page link) the addition of the T is legal and should be working.

Comment: Have you added the regex he mentioned (in the link) to your DateTime? Then only dates in the form "yyyy-mm-dd" will match.

Comment: No, I've kept it as simple as possible until I get this basic implementation working.

Comment: I just visited my routes.axd page on the API and tried to execute a request `http://localhost:51258/plots/range/2013-07-29T21:58:39/2013-07-29T21:58:39` and got this error `A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).` So it seems that `:` might actually be an illegal character ...

Comment: Based on the error I was seeing I decided to try it with just one date parameter as I was thinking that it might have been because of multiple dates but even with just one date I get the same error with this URL `http://localhost:51258/plots/range/2013-07-29T23:45:40`, no idea how to fix this at all ...

Comment: @evanmcdonnal - Not sure where you got the idea that it was nonstandard.  That's the [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard - including the `T`.  And it is understood by .Net.  Look at the `"o"` and `"s"` patterns [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

Comment: @MattJohnson yeah I was just plain wrong. I was looking at a table on MSDN and reading the wrong values, didn't think it was there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After doing a lot of reading it appears that it is possible to do what I was attempting to do but it requires relaxing a lot of useful security measures in order to do so.  Since there is a simple workaround it just doesn't make sense to relax these measures in light of increased security risks.

The error I was getting at the API was:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)
```

Obviously this is the colon characters used to separate the elements of the time portion of the `DateTime` string.  So I have made the following changes.

My Api action method now looks like this:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
[GET("range?{startDate:datetime}&{endDate:datetime}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
```

The dates are now defined as part of the query string rather than parts of the path itself.

To handle the creation of the query string I also have the following extension method:

```
public static string ToQueryString(this NameValueCollection source, bool removeEmptyEntries)
{
    return source != null ? "?" + String.Join("&", source.AllKeys
        .Where(key => !removeEmptyEntries || source.GetValues(key).Any(value => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)))
        .SelectMany(key => source.GetValues(key)
            .Where(value => !removeEmptyEntries || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            .Select(value => String.Format("{0}={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key), value != null ? HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value) : string.Empty)))
        .ToArray())
        : string.Empty;
}
```

Which is used in my client code like this:

```
var queryStringParams = new NameValueCollection
    {
        {"startDate", start.ToString(_dateService.DefaultDateFormatStringWithTime)},
        {"endDate", end.ToString(_dateService.DefaultDateFormatStringWithTime)}
    };

var response = httpClient.GetAsync(ApiRootUrl + "plots/range" + queryStringParams.ToQueryString(true)).Result;
```

The date service in my application simply provides the default date formatting string and uses this pattern:

```
"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"
```

The complete URI that is produced from this looks like:

```
http://localhost:51258/plots/range?startDate=2013-07-30T21%3A48%3A26&endDate=2013-08-06T21%3A48%3A26
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1):

`:` is a reserved character in the URL but it's acceptable in a query string. So if it works for your routing you could simply use:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
[GET("range")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(DateTime start, DateTime end)
```

and your URL request can look like this:

```
http://localhost:51258/plots/range?start=2013-07-29T21:58:39&end=2013-08-05T21:58:39
```