# issue with passing datetime fromDate toDate in url

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, asp.net-web-api

I issue passing data to url when I user input datetime fromDate and toDate it webapi I get bad request because of ':' BTW I use `[System.Web.Http.Route("api/{fromDate:datetime}/{toDate:datetime}/searchDateRange")]` on my web method but is not working can someone help me

Error

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the
>   client (:).
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: A potentially dangerous
>   Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path
>   value was detected from the client (:).]
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +9693412
>   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context) +53
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34248

```
    [System.Web.Http.Route("api/{fromDate:datetime}/{toDate:datetime}/searchDateRange")]
            public IEnumerable<FormViewModelBase> GetFormsByDateRange(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
            {
//codehere 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using HttpClient to Send Dates in URL Using AttributeRouting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067712/using-httpclient-to-send-dates-in-url-using-attributerouting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using datetime, the colon is obviously with the time, and as such the server does see the colon as a dangerous parameter.  Can you pass just the date component, not the time included?  Or, accept the parameters as string, and format the parameters to send a time without the :, but with another separator character.  Then you can parse the parameters and replace the separator back to colon and process accordingly.

Also, I would think the / in the date would be a problem with the recognition so are you using a date in XX-XX-XXXX or XXXX-XX-XX format?

Comment: I usually use following format :
yyyy-mm-ddThh-mm-ss

Answer (score 2):

I found solution

1- use momentjs  to convert it to utc and use format YYYYMMDDHHmmss

```
        var fromDate = moment(searchText.fromDateSearch).utc().format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss');
        var toDate = moment(searchText.toDateSearch).utc().format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss');
        url = ' api/' + fromDate + '/' + toDate + '/searchDateRange' ;
```

2- in webapi level convert string to datetime

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("api/{fromDate}/{toDate}/searchDateRange")]
            public IEnumerable<FormViewModelBase> GetFormsByDateRange(string fromDate, string toDate)
            {

                var fromDateSearch = DateTime.ParseExact(fromDate, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                var toDateSearch = DateTime.ParseExact(toDate, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
```

Comment: Really appreciate this one. Wasn't willing to go the query string route and this works really well.