# Passing a colon (:) to a webservice in a browser (for testing)

Tags: web-services, navigation

I would like to pass a date string to a web service for testing, using a browser. I've tried Chrome and Firefox and both error out with this:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:
```

The web service (RESTful) is accessed like this:

```
http://localhost:52936/Accounts/mod_date/2015-05-13T15%3A15%3A19
```

I've tried enclosing the date in quotes, but get the same error. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try a QueryString Parameter**

Since you are just performing testing, you should be able to pass your stringified `DateTime` value as a querystring parameter and it should avoid your service throwing a fit :

```
/Accounts/mod_date?yourDateParameterName=2015-05-13T15:15:19
```

Or if you wanted a more in-depth approach, you could consider [using a suggestion like the one mentioned in this related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18090249/557445).

**Explicitly Allow `:` Characters**

Scott Hanselman covers the idea of explicitly allowing certain characters to be passed to a service via a URL in [this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx). It basically allows you to define which values are considered "dangerous" when passed in and would simply involve you changing the `requestPathInvalidCharacters` setting within the `web.config` of your application from :

```
<httpruntime requestvalidationmode="2.0">
         requestPathInvalidCharacters="<,>,*,%,:,&,\"
         />
</httpruntime>
```

to :

```
<!-- Removes the colon ':' as a dangerous parameter -->
<httpruntime requestvalidationmode="2.0">
         requestPathInvalidCharacters="<,>,*,%,&,\"
         />
</httpruntime>
```

This is obviously very controversial stuff and may not be useful for all scenarios, but it *is* an option.

**Consider Postman (for Testing)**

Additionally for testing purposes, you might consider using a service like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), which is ideal for performing this type of API testing.

Comment: That worked: I edited web.config to include this:  <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,&amp;,\,?" /> but (for some reason) had to delete other httpRunTime config parameters. Still it now works.